# What does 探訪 mean here?

Tags: meaning, manga

Here is an excerpt from a manga I'm trying to read: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGqkb.png The context is that after a date this girl comes to the guy's house.

I'm having troubles understanding the sentence in the bottom right balloon. It says:

> 「探訪終わった…　このあとどうすれば」 "After 探訪 is over... What am I gonna do?"

Why would she use the word 探訪 here? From what I understand, it usually means researching or looking into something, especially with an entention to write a news article. What does that have to do with coming to a boyfriend's house?

Here is the full page if you need more context: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lj1oj.jpg

Comment: Does the word appear in previous pages?

Comment: @broccoliforest: no... here is the previous page - http://i.imgur.com/48uOaCR.jpg and the next page - http://i.imgur.com/aBVtcqB.jpg

Comment: Thanks. So it doesn't seem that she's doing some usual sense of "探訪" anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this sentence is certainly puzzling.

I have seen 探訪 used in the sense of "*visiting* someone's house" several times (for example, [お部屋探訪](http://www.chintai.net/news/category/visit/)), but I can't explain why the girl said 探訪「終わった」 in this context, because she didn't want to leave his house at this point.

One possibility is that she meant to imply "There are nothing more to talk about in this house". Maybe she was so nervous and wanted to talk with him in some way or another, like in the お部屋探訪 articles, but she failed to find a proper topic because his house was so simple and unremarkable. I feel so just because 探訪は終わった is said between 無駄なものがない部屋 and この後どうすれば, but this is just my speculation. Again, 探訪は終わった is *usually* understood as "My visit is over".

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/140660/meaning/m0u/%E6%8E%A2%E8%A8%AA/) Japanese-Japanese dictionary gives the following definition:

> 社会の出来事や実態を**その現場に行って**さぐり歩くこと。

I've highlighted the part, which I think is most relevant to your example: Actually going to a place to see/experience it for yourself. The kanji also hint at this meaning: (re)searching + visiting.

In your example (while not knowing the details of the story/context), I'm guessing she wanted to go to his place to see it for herself. To experience it. And now that she is there, and has seen it, she is unsure what will happen next / What is expected of her. As she notes, this is the first time she's been to a boy's room. His "おまえが来たいっつったんだよな？" also hints at her having expressed a wish to visit his place.

A loose translation might be something like:

> With the 'research' out of the way... Now what?

or:

> I've done what I came for... So what happens next?